# What is the search query string to look for item with multiple tags?

Tags: search, search-results, managed-metadata, taxonomy

I am using SharePoint 2013. I have add a managed metadata site column to multiple document libraries. In the search if I input `owstaxidmetadataalltagsinfo:keyword` it will return all items tagged "keyword" tag.

My question is what is the query string to list all items tagged with multiple tags? e.g. `owstaxidmetadataalltagsinfo:keywordA AND owstaxidmetadataalltagsinfo:keywordB`

Also, it there OOTB feature or sample code to facilitate users to submit above search? So that they don't need to learn the query string.

Answer (score 1):

Any query can be "saved" as a URL. So you could create a links list that included the various queries that you expect end users to run.

This TechNet article details some of the options for querying Managed Metadata fields. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj613136.aspx You are on the right track. You can either use the "taxid" version of the column which contains the ID of the term or you can use the string version of the field that contains the extracted term or terms. You would then AND them together.

Comment: I am able to query what I need now. Just one follow up question. I have 2 tags "Happy" and "Happy Birthday". By searching "owstaxidmetadataalltagsinfo:happy" I get both. How can I search exact tagged keyword "happy" and exclude "happy birthday"?

Comment: The colon ":" is a contains operator. If you just want "Happy" use the query managedproperty="happy".

Answer (score 0):

Try using below query string:

```
owstaxidmetadataalltagsinfo:keywordA OR owstaxidmetadataalltagsinfo:keywordB
```